# Effective testing of multiple students programming solutions

Tags: c++, unit-testing, automated-tests

As part of my lecture in C++ the students will have to solve assignments. Each solution shall implement the same functions with the same functionality and the same parameters (function name, return value, passing parameters). Only the code inside is different.

So i'm thinking about a way to test all solutions (around 30) in an effective way. Maybe the best way is to write a unit test as well as a shell script (or something similar) that compiles each solution once with the unit test and runs it.

But maybe there is a different and much better solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why unit tests are one of the most efficient types of automated testing is because the return of investment is relatively small (compared to other types of testing), so it makes perfect sense to me to write a verification suite of tests.

You might even go so far as to give the students the test suite instead of a specification written in prose. This could introduce them to the concept of Test-Driven Development (although we normally tend to write the tests iteratively, and not in batches).

Comment: Giving the students the test suite is an interesting point. Maybe i'm going to do that, it could save a lot of work (although i don't mind having lots of work for my students, but it must be effective).

Answer (score 1):

yes, unit tests are the obvious solution for most cases.

compiler warnings and static analysis is also useful.

timing the program's execution given a set of parameters is another fairly automated option -- depends on what you are interested in evaluating.

creating base classes with good diagnostics (which you can swap out the implementation for your evaluation if you prefer) is another option. you can also provide interfaces they must use, and hold two implementations. then exercise the programs as usual using the diagnostic implementation. it depends on what you are looking for.

Comment: +1 apart for the base class/interface stuff. Not all programs are expressed via classes (indeed, algorithms are functions, not classes).

Comment: in defense of classes/interfaces: it really depends on what the OP is looking for. example: if there's a good multithreading interface available, and it is required that they use it, then the test can analyze how many threads are created, the max number of threads which are active, and so on. if it's a collection type or allocator, then the amount of copying and/or allocation stats may be generated. again, it depends on what macs is looking for, and in what detail. some things are easier to test from that perspective. since they need only implement an interface... it may not be a bad option

Comment: I never said it was a bad option in itself. Just that it isn't always suited to the task at hand.

Comment: @Matthieu M. ah, ok - i was confused because i'd already stated that its use was limited.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something obvious, but wouldn't it be sufficient just to run the code several times with boundary-testing parameter values?

Comment: The point is, that i'm having around 30 solutions and i think it consumes too much time to compile each of it's own by hand. Or maybe **i'm** missing something?

Comment: @macs:  Why would you compile by hand?  I assume each student's work is submitted by email or on a website.  Just copy and paste its contents into a test framework, compile, and run.

Comment: I want to take the solution "as is", copy and paste tends to be error-prone sometimes, in my opinion. Therefore i wanted to use a script, collection all solutions (from different folders) and compile each of them against the test framework. But i thought there might be a smarter solution, that's why i was asking.

Comment: @macs: you can make it a requirement that "make test" in the directory to which the assignment's untarred compiles and runs the tests... no reason for you to know dig around trying to work out the dependencies.

Comment: @Tony: I'd never attempt to save work with the result of not considering the ideas of the student in his/her solution. Testing if it's working shall just be the first step, giving me a slight overview. Since their using premake4 it should be easy to add a "make test" to every solution. Thank you for this suggestion.